# Incompatibility click and black versions with Poetry ( ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click' )

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

The incompatibility between click 8.1.1 and black <=22.1.0 has been reported and apparently fixed [here](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2964)

But apparently still a problem with poetry, as reported (and also apparently fixed) [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5375)

Config:

- Poetry (1.1.13)
- MacOS 10.15.7
- [my pyproject.toml](https://gist.github.com/charlottegiseleweil/5e82deceaa59cc10dd984440c364451c).

Running `poetry run pre-commit run --all-files` results systematically in:

```
black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- exit code: 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charlotteweil1/.cache/pre-commit/repoqg3mkzrn/py_env-python3.9/bin/black", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(patched_main())
  File "/Users/charlotteweil1/.cache/pre-commit/repoqg3mkzrn/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 1372, in patched_main
    patch_click()
  File "/Users/charlotteweil1/.cache/pre-commit/repoqg3mkzrn/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 1358, in patch_click
    from click import _unicodefun
ImportError: cannot import name '_unicodefun' from 'click' (/Users/charlotteweil1/.cache/pre-commit/repoqg3mkzrn/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/__init__.py)
```

I've tried removing the whole `repoqg3mkzrn` directory in `.cache/pre-commit` and re-installing pre-commit, but behavior is identical :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to the Poetry application. This is related to contributing to Poetry and better suited in the issue tracker. Answer is here: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5375#issuecomment-1090420084

Comment: @finswimmer just remove the poetry tag then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'll want to check your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` -- you almost certainly have an outdated version of black configured there.  the easiest fix is to run `pre-commit autoupdate` to get to the latest version

alternatively, if you would like to remain on an outdated version of `black` you can force an older version of click:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: ...  # whatever old version
    hooks:
    -   id: black
        additional_dependencies: ['click<8.1']
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit